# LINQ query doesn't compile

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Partial Class ProtectedContent_Books Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private database As BooksDataContext()


    Protected Sub authorsLinqDataSource_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs) Handles authorsLinqDataSource.Selecting
        e.Result =
        From author In database.Authors
        Select Name = author.FirstName & " " & author.LastName, author.AuthorID()
    End Sub
End Class
```

when I code `From author In database.Authors` it says *Authors is not a member of `System.Array`*!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by

```
Private database As BooksDataContext()
```

you declare an array of `BooksDataContext` objects. I suspect you want to do:

```
Private database As New BooksDataContext()
```

This only declares one new instance of `BooksDataContext`.
You might also want to check the `SELECT` part of your query as it will not compile. If you want to select a new anonymous object, change your query as follows:

```
e.Result = From author In database.Authors
    Select New With { .Name = author.FirstName & " " & author.LastName, 
                      .AuthorId =  author.AuthorID }
```

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasourceselecteventargs.result%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) shows a sample on how to use the event.